# Drawing a sprite on Raycast collision point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to emit a raycast **from the player object** and project a crosshair texture **onto the world position** the crosshair is aimed at. The crosshair should not overlap with the player and it should also only be emited **in front of the Player gameObject**.

I have tried this so far:

```
    private float range = 100f;
    public Texture crosshair;
    private Rect crosshairPos;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        crosshairPos.x = ray.GetPoint(100f).x;
        crosshairPos.y = ray.GetPoint(100f).y;
        Graphics.DrawTexture(crosshairPos, crosshair);
```

Edit: After some testing, I am currently on the following snippet of code:

```
    void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    crosshairPos.x = ray.GetPoint(5f).x;
    crosshairPos.y = ray.GetPoint(5f).y;
    crosshairPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(crosshairPos);
    Vector2 crosshairPosSize = new Vector2(crosshair.width, crosshair.height);
    Graphics.DrawTexture(new Rect((Vector2)crosshairPos, crosshairPosSize), crosshair);
}
```

I am however still unable to see a projected crosshair.

Comment: So to understand correctly, are you trying to have some sort of sprite projected at the collision point of the raycast? Like an actual laser being projected from the player in the game world? (as opposed to just it being projected by the camera center point?)

Comment: @MylonasK. Not really a laser, but an invisible raycast that spawns a crosshair sprite at the end point of said raycast. If that's not really possible or useful the crosshair could still overlap the player, but in that case the crosshair still needs to move on the camera for it to be aiming right in front of the player. Does that make sense?

Comment: do you need the billboard behaviour towards the camera ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `Ray` from a `GameObject` you get a `Vector` in the world coordinate system. (The game world where your player is).

`Graphics.DrawTexture()` uses *screen* coordinates to draw the texture on screen.

Consider using [`Camera.Main.WorldToScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) to change the world points that you get from `Ray` into points you can display on screen.

Here's an example of that

```cs
Vectors crosshairPos = new Vector3();
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    crosshairPos.x = ray.GetPoint(100f).x;
    crosshairPos.y = ray.GetPoint(100f).y;
    
    crosshairPos = Camera.Main.WorldToScreenPoint(crosshairPos);

    Graphics.DrawTexture((Vector2)crosshairPos, crosshair);
}
```

Comment: I edited the post with what I'm currently left on. After a bit of testing the code does not return any errors but it still does not show a crosshair.

Comment: Using the OnGUI function and GUI instead of Graphics does draw something on the UI panel, just in a strange location. I'll test some more to see if I can fix the position of the crosshair.

Comment: Make sure you understand the RECT and UI coordinate system. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). Furthermore (0,0) of the texture is a corner, if you want to center it you'll have to shift where you draw the texture by half the width and height of the texture